# Vue 2.0 instance is not hearing events emitted by vue-router components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using Vue 2.0-rc.6 (latest at the moment) and Vue-router 2.0-rc.5 (latest at the moment).

I tried to do `this.$emit('custom-event')` in one of my router components, and `this.$on('custom-event', () => { console.log('I heard an event') })` in my Vue instance but the event was not being listened. The router component itself was hearing the event but not the Vue instance.

Any idea?

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnj71j8f/).

Comment: I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wanxe/vnj71j8f/1/

https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication (Thanks to Mani: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377977/how-to-create-a-hook-with-events-between-vue-2-0-components/40378611?noredirect=1#comment68012089_40378611)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to LinusBorg in http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/5235/vue-2-0-instance-is-not-hearing-events-emitted-by-vue-router-components/2 for pointing out that an event from $emit is not propagated to the parent instance.

I didn't make it work though by using the suggested solution by LinusBorg. Instead, I made it working by doing `this.$router.app.$emit('eventname')`

Answer (score 21):

An event from $emit is not propagated to the parent instance.
The parent has to listen for it on the component in the template actively.

```
<router-view @eventname="callbackMethod" />
```

Answer (score 2):

using watcher we can achieve the same thing, Mean when my routes are updated then we can catch an event through watcher.

```
    watch: {
        '$route': function(to, from) {
              console.log('To :', to.path); // current route
              console.log('from:', from.path); // old route
         }
    }
```