# How to create a hook with events between VUE 2.0 components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've created two [dynamic](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) components. Now, using [events: $emit/$on](https://vuejs.org/api/#Instance-Methods-Events)
**what I need is to fire the "logThat(someObj)" method  of the component-two passing the arguments** as you can see in this fiddle:

```
Vue.component('component-one', {
    template: '#template-a',
    methods: {
        onClick() {
            const someObj = {
                foo: "foo",
                bar: "bar"
            }

            vm.$emit('selected', someObj)
            vm.currentView ='component-two';
        }
    }
});

//Any hint??
/*vm.$on('selected', (someObj) => {
    this.logThat(someObj)
})*/

Vue.component('component-two', {
    template: '#template-b',
    methods: {
        onClick() {
            vm.currentView ='component-one';
        },
        logThat(someObj) {
            console.log(someObj);
       }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wanxe/yuh71e1o/

If anyone has any suggestions of how to handle this, it will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you are supposed to use [Non-parent-child communication](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) as given in the docs.

But in your current example, it will not work. Reason: Your components 'one' and 'two' are getting created and destroyed as you move back and forth.

Here is your updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/yuh71e1o/4/. Here are the changes:

Event bus:

```js
var bus = new Vue();
```

Sending event from component-one:

```js
bus.$emit('selected', someObj);
```

Receiving event in component-two:

```js
created: function() {
   console.log("Created component-two, listening for 'selected' event");
   bus.$on('selected', this.logThat);
}
```

If you open the dev console and observe the logs, you will notice that component-two gets created multiple times and the old ones keep listening as they are not fully destroyed.

To overcome this, you need to move away from dynamic components, and have both your `component-one` and `component-two` created at the same time on your root template. You may show / hide based on whichever view you desire, using `v-show` (not `v-if` which again destroys the component instance). Then you can use the event bus to communicate, as detailed in the [Non-parent-child communication docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication).

Comment: First, thanks so much for helping me better understand the dynamic components. As I can see in your example, when fires component two the first time, it is only instantiated, but not the 'selected' event is triggered. However, the second time I get the expected result.

It's clear that I need to use static components and use v-show to switch as you tell me. But assuming you have the variable "ShowMe", where I declare? In the instantiation of vue, in each of the components, both?

Comment: If you click for a third or fourth time, you will notice more interesting results in the original fiddle - the old `component-two` is never destroyed. Instead it gets recreated every time, leading to unpredictable results. Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/yuh71e1o/5/ - In this, I have used `v-show` to show / hide components instead of dynamically switching between them. Here you will find the results you expect.

Comment: Great!! Thanks again!